# IOS 7 Sockets refused

Tags: ios, ios7

I have been carrying out tests using sockets, using sdk 5-6. The app talks to the server and the server talks back no problem.

No firewalls are present, the network is private, and ipad 1/2/3 all work running the socket app and talking to the server.

However, when I run the app on an ipad running sdk 7, the connection to the server gets refused - nothing has changed other than running the app on an ipad which has sdk 7.
Also when the server tries speaking to the app running on the ipad, the server reports that the ipad is refusing the connection.

This appears to be a break in the way the sdk works from 5/6 to 7. Can anyone confirm, and if possible highlight a work around.

Cheers

```
    char [1000];
    ...
    NSMutableString *msg = [NSMutableString stringWithUTF8String:buffer];
```

The buffer contians the encrypted data, but after the assignment msg is set to nil?

Comment: Can you provide your code of server socket(listening) and client socket(caller)?

Comment: Have the answer the data needs  to be cleaned data sent from the server(windows) adds a new line to flush its buffer which causes issues when received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using NSMutableString stringWithUTF8 use stringWithCString this works across all the platforms I have been testing so far..., this removes the unwanted carriage return and line feed. Also it removes the unwanted terminating block code x17.